# `".maintenance.flag" cannot be touched Warning` Error while installing magento2 after admin user creation - Linux

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I got stuck (94% progress) in exception while installing magento2 after user creation. I have enabled the php error reporting on but not Luck.

Then i have tried to debug from terminal(CLI) and got exception. below are error messages please provide me solution.

Your inputs is really appreciable.

**CLI command :**

```
user@xxx-Aspire-Series:/var/www/html/magento2$ php setup/index.php install --db_host=localhost --db_name=magento2 --db_user=root --db_pass=root --base_url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ --backend_frontname=admin --admin_firstname=Admin --admin_lastname=admin --admin_email=abhi@magentodeveloper.com --admin_username=admin --admin_password=!-!&*#@123
```

**Error Occurred:**

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...
[Progress: 1 / 93]
Enabling Maintenance Mode...
======================================================================
   The application has thrown an exception!
======================================================================
Magento\Framework\Filesystem\FilesystemException
The file or directory "/var/www/html/magento2/var/.maintenance.flag" cannot be touched Warning!touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied
----------------------------------------------------------------------
/var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:386
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(198): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->touch('/var/www/html/m...', NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/MaintenanceMode.php(95): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->touch('.maintenance.fl...')
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/module/Magento/Setup/src/Model/Installer.php(485): Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode->set(1)
#3 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->setMaintenanceMode(1)
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/module/Magento/Setup/src/Model/Installer.php(263): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/module/Magento/Setup/src/Controller/ConsoleController.php(312): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters))
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): Magento\Setup\Controller\ConsoleController->installAction()
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Console\Request), Object(Zend\Console\Response))
#12 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#15 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(313): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/index.php(48): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#17 {main}
======================================================================
Previous Exception(s):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need write permissions for the var-subfolder, in this case especially the var/.maintenance.flag file.